# Internet Explorer Automation - IE Not Responding and VBA code hangs

Tags: vba, ms-access, internet-explorer, automation, freeze

I created a VBA code written in Access to loop over a list of more than 5000 weblinks.

- I need to navigate the links and then click buttons or fill
  information in forms
- Given the point before, I'm forced to use InternetExplorer Application (cannot use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP)
- I've implemented a loop over the data I have in MAccess and then for each record I need to navigate a webpage
- I check IE busy and readystate before proceeding with data retrieval from inner/outer-TEXT/HTML page and before clicking on
  button/links
- The code works perfectly, but after hundreds of iterations, it stops working and Access/VBA becomes irresponsive
- I open and quit IExplorer Application for each single iteration of the loop
- I use DoEvents and Sleep 200 in the busy/readystate loops
- I check the second elapsed in the loop and after 20 seconds I quit the IE application, kill all the IE processes and retry
- I verified that, when the hang happens, the IE webpage is crashed and not responding (recover webpage message) and when I'm able to enter the debug of VBA code, if I press F8 to continue, it simply doesn't go to the next line (the
  breakpoint is on the line of IE Busy or IE Readystate check)
- When I then manually kill iexplorer.exe process in task manager, and only then, the code starts working again and saying that iexplorer istance is not linked to code... (as I killed it)
- I have Win7 Enterprise on 64 bit architecture, Office 2016 and IE11.0.9600.18837

Here a snippet of the code:

```
        StartTime = Timer
        Do While Not CheckIfIEIsHanging And IE.Busy
            DoEvents
            StatusBar ("Caricamento in corso. Attendi... (Busy " & Round(SecondsElapsed) & " sec)")
            SecondsElapsed = (Timer - StartTime)
            If (SecondsElapsed > 20) Then
                IE.Quit
                Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 'CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
                IE.Visible = False
                GoTo reload
            End If
            Sleep 200
        Loop
        Do While Not CheckIfIEIsHanging And IE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
            StatusBar ("Caricamento in corso. Attendi... (NotReady " & Round(SecondsElapsed) & " sec)")
            SecondsElapsed = (Timer - StartTime)
            If (SecondsElapsed > 20) Then
                IE.Quit
                Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 'CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
                IE.Visible = False
                GoTo reload
            End If
            Sleep 200
        Loop


        'Hanging???
        If CheckIfIEIsHanging Then
            Call Sound
            KillProcess ("iexplore.exe")
            Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 'CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
            IE.Visible = False
            GoTo reload
        End If
```

Comment: Seems that no one is able to handle my request...

Comment: I'm curious if you ever found a solution to this. I have a similar problem, I download PDFs from a website thousands of times. Usually, after about 20 downloads Internet Explorer stops responding and forces me to close. This stops my macro. I do not close IE each time because I need to log into the site so I just continue to navigate my original IE page to avoid logging in thousands of times.